# Create an bash alias to link change directory in terminal

Tags: bash

I have written the following code (and added it to my .bash_aliases file in Ubuntu) to change directory in my terminal to the project I enter. E.g. if I enter `go project1` it will search through my freelance and side_projects directory and if it has the "project1" directory it will cd into that directory.

```
alias go='goToProject'

function goToProject
{
    echo 'Redirecting to' $1
    if [ -d "side_projects/$1" ]; then
        cd ~/Documents/projects/personal/side_projects/$1
    fi
    if [ -d "freelance/$1" ]; then
        cd ~/Documents/projects/personal/freelance/$1
    fi
}
```

However when I run this code it prints the "Redirecting to project1" but doesn't change directory. Can anyone see an obvious error in my code?

Comment: Ok, looks good. Your question?

Comment: What if the same subdirectory exists under side_projects and freelance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or add this to your .bashrc:

```
CDPATH="$CDPATH:$HOME/Documents/projects/personal/side_projects:$HOME/Documents/projects/personal/freelance"
```

and you can use `cd project1` from everywhere.

Comment: Nice! Never heard about `CDPATH`!

Comment: Nice - had no idea this was possible. Thanks Cyrus.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the alias, just this:

```
function go
{
    echo "Redirecting to $1"
    if [ -d "side_projects/$1" ]; then
        cd ~/Documents/projects/personal/side_projects/"$1"
    fi
    if [ -d "freelance/$1" ]; then
        cd ~/Documents/projects/personal/freelance/"$1"
    fi
}
```

Btw, note that I've added missing quotes.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the edit! I missed that `~` expansion won't work between double quotes

Comment: Thanks for your answer hek2mgl - It still doesn't work for me it runs but just returns to the same directory (same as my code was doing). I've opted to use Cyrus's answer thou as it works really well.